# Emit argument type as XML element in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, xml-serialization

Suppose I have the following method defined on a WCF service:

```
[OperationContract]
void Draw(Shape obj)
```

and I have typical Circle and Square classes which derive from Shape.

Using built-in WCF XML serialization this would turn into something like:

```
<obj ... xsd:type="Circle"/>
```

Is there *any* way to control serialization in such a way that serialization emits

`<circle/> <square/>` etc.

instead? (I know this does not map the 'XSD-compliant inheritance' as such)

Many thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Since your method is returning void, I am guessing that you Re trying to get the wsdl to show various types.  Have you tried using the known types attribute?